# Installing game on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, games

I'm trying to install a video game I just downloaded (Heroes of Newerth, and I downloaded the Linux version. The game is a .sh extension.), but I'm having some trouble. I downloaded the newest Ubuntu version monday, I think it's something around 16.04 or something.

I tried to look at some tutorials on the internet and many of them said I had to go to properties>permissions> check "allow this file to be executed" and after that double click the file and a dialog box would appear with the option of running the installation of the game, but no such box showed up.

Do you know how I can install this game? This is my first time using linux and I don't know that much about computers (only the most basic stuff) and nothing about programing which makes using the terminal very difficult, so please so I guess I need simple answers.

My preferred answer would be how to get that promised dialog box with the option to run the game as a normal program.

Comment: `chmod +x file.sh` .... And : `./file.sh`

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no idea what this means

Comment: @HenriqueTyrrell - See my answer.

Comment: Thank you guys, I was finally able to succesfully install the game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your terminal and `cd` into the directory you game is on, and then enter the following commands:

```
cd ~/your/games/directory
chmod u+x game.sh
./game.sh
```

Also, you can open the game directory (Downloads perhaps) from file manager and **Right Click -> Open in Terminal** for your convenience.

Comment: I doubt `sudo` is required.

Answer (score 4):

First, open a terminal. (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>)

Next, `cd` into the directory containing the file. So for example, if your file was in the Downloads directory in a folder called "coolgame", you would run:

```
cd Downloads/coolgame
```

To confirm that you are in the right folder, run:

```
ls -l
```

And make sure you see it in the list.

Next, you need to give it the executable bit, so that Ubuntu allows you to run it. Assuming the installer is called "install.sh", you would do that like so:

```
chmod +x install.sh
```

**Finally**, to run it, all you have to do is run:

```
./install.sh
```

---

Now if running the installer with the above command says "you need to be root" or something like that, then you would need to run this command instead to run the installer:

```
sudo ./install.sh
```